# MySQL statement using WHERE AND OR

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I try to execute the following, what am I missing here ?

```
DELETE FROM escrow WHERE  host = '$name' OR challenger = '$name' AND id='$match_id'
```

Comment: Telling us what is happening vs what is expected would be a great start. We have no idea if the query runs but does not have the desired result, or if nearby kittens are catching on fire.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `AND` and `OR` together in any circumstances in any programming language **ALWAYS** use brackets. There is an implicit order which gets evaluated first (the `AND` or the `OR` condition) but you usually don't know the order and shouldn't be in need to look it up in the manual

Also use [Prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) for SQL queries which depends on variables.

In your case you either write

```
... WHERE (host = ? OR challenger = ?) AND id = ?
```

or

```
... WHERE host = ? OR (challenger = ? AND id = ?)
```

depending on what condition you want.

Also, when a SQL query fails for whatever reason check the error message you get from the database. It will tell you whats wrong with the query. However, a valid query which returns no rows (because the WHERE condition don't match for any row) is still a valid query and not an error, the result is just empty.